# Creating a function that returns all capitalized words in a sentence (commas excluded)

Tags: python, python-3.4

I need to create a function that will return all capitalized words from a sentence into a list. If the word ends with a comma, you need to exclude it (the comma). This is what I came up with:

```
def find_cap(sentence):
    s = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word.startswith(word.capitalize()):
            s.append(word)
        if word.endswith(","):
            word.replace(",", "")
    return s
```

My problem: The function seems to work, but if I have a sentence and a word is in quotes, it returns the word in quotes even if it isn't capitalized. Also the commas aren't replaced, even though I used `word.replace(",", "")`. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a regular expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are an immutable type in Python. This means that `word.replace(",", "")` will not mutate the string `word` is pointing at; it will return a new string with the commas replaced.

Also, since this is a stripping problem (and commas are not likely to be in the middle of words), why not use `string.strip()` instead?

Try something like this:

```
import string

def find_cap(sentence):
    s = []
    for word in sentence.split():

        # strip() removes each character from the front and back of the string
        word = word.strip(string.punctuation)

        if word.startswith(word.capitalize()):
            s.append(word)
    return s
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to do this:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'This Is a String With a Comma, Capital and small Letters'
>>> newList = re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)', string)
>>> newList
['This', 'Is', 'String', 'With', 'Comma', 'Capital', 'Letters']
```

Comment: Looks good but I think he needs the entire word, not just the first letter

Answer (score 0):

using `re.findall`:

```
  a= "Hellow how, Are You"
  re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+',a)
  ['Hellow', 'Are', 'You']
```